# How to fix IE9 throwing SCRIPT1028 error, using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, console, internet-explorer-9, angularjs

I use [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) in my single-page application. Somewhere I have defined a button like this

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="doSeekTo({{todo.position}});doPlay();">
```

This button, when clicked, invokes the javascript function with the given parameter in double curly braces, as usual with AngularJS.

This all works well in IE9, but when looking at the error console, it says “Expected identifier, string or number” at the position of my curly braces.

**How to get rid of this error?** It makes me feel uncomfortable.

Comment: Are you using `ng-app` to load Angular, or through a `bootstrap` call?

Comment: @rxgx I use ng-app. You can see yourself: http://quir.li/player.html However, I have changed the way I do it now according to Max's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular, you're not supposed to use the built in `onclick` event, but rather Angular's `ng-click` event. That way you can write

```
ng-click="doSeekTo(todo.position);doPlay()"
```

Comment: This sounds reasonable, but when trying exactly as you suggest, it does not work. There is no action taken. I will investigate with your tip as basis.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not bring this to work. I have to say that the button is not the submit button. And I am no AngularJS expert yet too...

Comment: Finally, I managed to succeed. doSeekTo() was just an ordinary global function. I not have it defined on the $scope, and now it works like expected. Thanks @Max.

Comment: In Angular, nothing should be global. Everything should be in Controllers, Directives, Services and such within the Angular world so that Angluar can make it all play nicely together. If you're going to use Angular, you have to use it all the way.

Answer (score 1):

IE9 is parsing the HTML before your angularjs code modifies it. Maybe some indirection like this would help ...

```
<button class="btn btn-success" paramvalue="{{todo.position}}" onclick="doSeekTo(this.paramvalue);doPlay();">
```

Comment: Nice idea. If I don't bring @Max's tip to fly, I will resort to this one.

Comment: This seems to work partially, the doSeekTo function is invoked, the parameter received inside the function however is undefined.

Comment: @Marcel - if "this.paramvalue" isn't working try "this.getAttribute('paramvalue')"

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to enclose the {{}} in single quotes such that IE interprets it as a string:

```
<button class="btn btn-success"> onclick="doSeekTo('{{todo.position}}');doPlay();">
```